# How can I clean this df colum in python and then get row index in correspondence of a string?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/key/date/2021/html/index_include.en.html"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
titles = soup.select(".title a")
dates = soup.select(".date")

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': zip(dates), 'Titles': zip(titles)}) # dataframe
```

What I want to do is to clean both columns removing `([],)` around the text. Then, I would like to keep only the rows that contain "Lagarde" in the second column. This is what I tried so far:

```
# to remove square and round brackets 

df.replace('([],)', '', regex=True)

# to look for rows that only have "Lagarde" in the second column

df[df['Titles'].str.contains('Lagarde', regex = False)]
```

I fail in either case and I don't understand why.

Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're getting "Dates" and "Titles" as bs4.element.Tag objects. To turn them into strings, you can add:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df[column])):
        df[column][i] = df[column][i].get_text()
```

When you do this, you're left with pure strings. Then you can search for any pattern you'd like. For example, if you run:

```
df[df['Titles'].str.contains('Lagarde', regex = False)]
```

it returns only the rows that contain "Lagarde".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run the loop I get: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_text' `. Any idea?

Comment: That's because you're zipping "dates" and "titles" which turns them into tuples. Thus, you should remove zip like this:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Titles': titles})